# How do I pull a name from a class in an Array?

Tags: ruby

Okay, this is a little hard to explain but I will try (For starters I am only just learning to code so it may be something super simple I'm missing..)

I created a few classes, I put a name in those classes, I put them in an array, I then chose one at random and try to puts the name, and it outputs blank.

Am I doing this all completely wrong? I've been learning ruby for about 3 months now so I'm sure there is a lot I don't know.

```
 class A
  attr :name
  def set_name
    @name = "Aaa"
  end

  def get_name
    return @name
  end
end

class B
  attr :name
  def set_name
    @name = "Bbb"
  end

  def get_name
    return @name
  end
end

class C
  attr :name
  def set_name
    @name = "Ccc"
  end

  def get_name
    return @name
  end
end

name_a = A.new
name_b = B.new
name_c = C.new
which_name = Array.new

which_name[0] = name_a
which_name[1] = name_b
which_name[2] = name_c

roll = rand(max 3)

puts which_name[roll].get_name
```

Comment: "Am I doing this all completely wrong?" - doing what? There is nothing in this question that describes what this code is actually supposed to accomplish.

Comment: It does seem odd that you're creating three different classes that are exactly the same. This should be three instances of the same class unless the classes themselves have differences.

Comment: Hint: `names = [ A.new, B.new, C.new ]` and `random_name = names.sample`.

Comment: Ruby avoids `get_` and `set_` prefixes. Instead use `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then chose one at random and try to puts the name, and it outputs
>   blank.

You never called the `#set_name` method in your code. You can add this:

```
name_a.set_name
name_b.set_name
name_c.set_name
```

Also, you probably want to look into [`#attr_accessor`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/attr_accessor/).